# export attributes to csv from magento

Tags: magento, csv, attributes

I found a working code that exports the attributes to the browser interface,
like this:
[image]

this is the code:'

```
  <?php

chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
umask(0);

$productModel = Mage::getModel('Mage_Catalog_Model_Product');
$categoryModel = Mage::getModel('Mage_Catalog_Model_Category');
$resource = Mage::getModel('core/resource');
$db = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

$attributes = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)->getAttributeCollection();

foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
    #if(!$attribute->getIsUserDefined()) continue;
    if($attribute->getEntityTypeId() != 4) continue;
    if($attribute->getFrontendInput() != 'select' && $attribute->getFrontendInput() != 'multiselect') continue;
    echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel(). ' (' . $attribute->getAttributeCode() . ')' . "\n";
    foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) as $option) {
        if(empty($option['label'])) continue;
        echo "," . $option['label']."\n";
    }
    echo "================,=================\n";
}
```

I would like to export this data to a csv, but I dont know how.
As another question I would also like to export the attribute sets and not only the attributes, is this possible?

Thanks in advance!